# R-Studio freezes when trying to load data

Tags: r, rstudio

I was trying to load the dataset from this file https://github.com/WinVector/zmPDSwR/blob/master/Custdata/custdata.tsv
and RStudio freezes and crashes every time. How can I tell if there is something particular with the datafile or RStudio is unable to handle it? How would I be able to get this data into R?

Comment: What code are you using to read the file? It loads just file with `read.delim`. (Note that you cannot just load that URL, it returns the HTML from GitHub. You need to load the *raw* version of the file.)

Comment: What is the exact code are you using to get the dataset?

Comment: You can directly download the dataset, if that suits your deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide you with a possible alternative.

I always get a strange error whenever I try to do the online-data-pull, so what I do is, I download the dataset and keep it in my project folder and do my work with that.

As far as the dataset is concerned, it is the standard tsv format.

A code-snippet for your reference is:

```
mydata <- read.table("~path/dataset.tsv",sep="\t", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: `mydata <- read.table("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WinVector/zmPDSwR/master/Custdata/custdata.tsv",sep="\t", header=TRUE)` works fine for me though if you had a problem pulling it down would work as you point out.